# Usar if no evento onPress

Tags: javascript, react-native

Estou tentando usar um `if` assim:

```
<Button
      iconRight={{
        name: 'search',
        type: 'font-awesome'
      }}
      title='BUSCAR'
      buttonStyle={{
        marginTop: 15,
        borderRadius: 7,
        backgroundColor:'#2C5CAA'
      }}
      onPress={(function() {if (this.state.busca.length > 0){
        alert(this.state.busca.length);
      }else{
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Lista', {
                                                              busca: this.state.busca,
                                                              city: this.state.city })}
      })
    }
     />
```

Porém, estou recebendo um erro na variável `this.state.busca`:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.busca')

Como resolver?

Comment: Desculpe não ter inserido o código completo, é um button. Alterei a pergunta @wmsouza

Comment: Qual o conteúdo do `this.state.busca` o bom seria vc criar um snack

Comment: Provavelmente o contexto do `this` está para a função anonima dentro do `onPress()`, você precisa dar um bind no contexto da sua classe para poder ter acesso ao `state` do componente

Answer (score 0):

Muito provavelmente em `this.state.busca` o `this` está ligado ao context da sua função anônima dentro do `onPress()` tente fazer um `bind()` para passar o contexto da sua classe para o `this`:

```
<Button

  iconRight={{
    name: 'search',
    type: 'font-awesome'
  }}

  title='BUSCAR'

  buttonStyle={{
    marginTop: 15,
    borderRadius: 7,
    backgroundColor:'#2C5CAA'
  }}

  onPress={(function() {
    if (this.state.busca.length > 0){
        alert(this.state.busca.length);
    } else {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Lista', {
            busca: this.state.busca,
            city: this.state.city 
        })
    }
  }).bind(this)

} />
```

Recomendo que isole essa função em outra parte do seu código para que fique com uma legibilidade melhor.